# Mesh symmetry - help me get this part right please

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new at this 3D modeling and I stumbled on a problem:

I added a cylinder to make a glass bowl and I lost the symmetry somehow. I want them at the same heights.

Can someone guide me on how to get it right?

[image]

Comment: Hi. This should help with taking clearer screenshots: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: Try using Mirror modifier. Or if the bowl has the shape of a half-sphere, just add UV Sphere and delete one half of it.

Comment: Look into 'Snapping'. It's the magnet in the top middle of this image, shows a magnet. By enabling and selecting the 'Vertex' option. You should be able to select any vertex, and use your move(g key) and your axis of choice. In this case the Z axis(z key).